# trying to do facebook like automatic content scrolling but the data is not showing correctly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

designing a Facebook like scrolling system the data shows but it does not show the first 5 values and it shows the values in repetition

here is my code:

view:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var total_record = 0;
    var total_groups = <?php echo $total_data; ?>;  
    $('#results').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>user/load_more", {'group_no':total_record}, function() {total_record++;});
    $(window).scroll(function() {       
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  
        {           
            if(total_record <= total_groups)
            {
                loading = true; 
                $('.loader_image').show(); 
                $.post('<?php echo site_url() ?>user/load_more',{'group_no': total_record},
                function(data){ 
                    if (data != "") {                               
                        $("#results").append(data);                 
                        $('.loader_image').hide();                  
                        total_record++;
                    }
                });     
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

then my controller

```
public function load_more()
    {

        $group_no = $this->input->post('group_no');
        //print_r($group_no);
        $content_per_page = 10;
        $start = ceil($group_no * $content_per_page);
        //print_r($start);
        $this->load->model('Pmodel');
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $all_content = $this->Pmodel->get_all_content($user_id,$start,$content_per_page);
        // echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($all_content);

        if(isset($all_content) && is_array($all_content) && count($all_content)) : 
            foreach ($all_content as $key => $content) :
                 echo '<li>'.$content->status.'</li>';
                 echo '<p>'.$content->status_image.'</p>';                 
            endforeach;                                
        endif; 
        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->data['labels_message']); exit;
    }
```

and then my model

```
public function get_all_content($id,$start,$content_per_page)
    {   


        $query=$this->db->select('*')
        ->from('post_status')

        ->where('user_id',$id)
        ->limit($start,$content_per_page)
        ->get();


        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($query);
        //var_dump($query);

        $result = $query->result();
       //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($result);
        return $result;

    }
```

how to show the data according to the database
let me add a image for database

[image: database]

Comment: you want to show some data on load then after scroll it will load next 10 data?

Comment: yeah even if i do it with 5 it shows the first 5 selected data in repetition

Comment: make sure `total_record` is getting updated each time

Comment: total record is getting updated as 0,1,2,3,4